# Config.yml Using Plugin LobbyCompass giving error

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I am having this problem: I have configured my `config.yml` on a plugin called `LobbyCompass`, its a plugin on *minecraft* for my server and its version v2.5

This is the error I am getting when I try to open up the compass:

```
[.17:27:58 INFO]: [LobbyCompass] A open-compass error has been thrown. Please check your config or contact a developer if the problem persist.
```

I do not think this is a problem with the plugin and I think this is a problem with my `config.yml`. Could somebody fix this for me?

https://hastebin.com/iqegomegam.coffeescript

Comment: You will have better luck finding an answer talking to the guy who made LobbyCompass. Stack Overflow is not here to help you use software (of any kind, including mods), its here to help you *write* software.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to help you, there are multiple situations, if none of them described here help then please comment on what your situation is

**1**) If you have a plugin you will have to go to the plugin.yml and in that file you will have to add this line

```
dependent: LobbyCompass
```

**2**) If you have a server then in the server.properties you will have to add this line of code

```
depend: [LobbyCompass]
```

**3**) If none of those work then go in the game with that error and type in `/plugins`. If LobbyCompass is there then you must contact the developers because there is an error, or you can download a different version of the plugin. If it is not there then you must delete the plugin, delete all cache and then reinstall the plugin.

**For all of those solution you must remove all other plugins and their configs temporarily**